# Extending a java swing button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want each JButton to also have a number or id associated with it. That is why I decided to extend the JButton class to make a class SuperJButton.

How do I include the value of the id/number in the action event generated when this button is clicked so that the class which responds to this action can access the id ?

Comment: You can get the source form which action is generated, in your case the *super* button, by using `ae.getSource()` where `ae` is the reference of `ActionEvent`. This way you can have access to your button by which action is generated and then can get the id associated with it.

Comment: Why you want to include id field into it.? Is it used just to investigate which button is clicked.?

Comment: @VallabhPatade - Exactly. Why process the text String associated with that button ? Thats what all the sample code on the net does to respond to an action.

Comment: don't _extend_, JSomething are meant to be used as-are. Anyway, why do you want to id the button? It already has a variety of options (f.i. its name property, actionCommand/name/arbitrary value on the Action, clientProperty) - why doesn't any of those fit your needs? Oh, just noticed that the why already was asked - without a convincing answer, though: there is nothing wrong with a string ...

Comment: @kleopatra: that's not true. It's perfectly OK to sub-class JComponent (or any other *JXxxx* class). That's the advantage of having an object-oriented GUI framework. Any library/framework building on top of Swing will sub-class Swing components (think NetBeans platform or the SwingX library)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - it _can_ be done technically, but you would need a very good reason to actually do it (which this is not, as there're already enough variants for id'ing, your answer offering one of them :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative which doesn't require sub-classing, could be to use `JComponent.putClientProperty(Object key, Object value)` to store the ID associated with your button.

It can be retrieved using `getClientProperty(Object key)`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
   JComponent comp = (JComponent)e.getSource();
   KeyObject kObj = (KeyObject)comp.getClientProperty("button.id");
}
```

That might be a bit more flexible as you can attach this ID to every button without the need to use an application specific code e.g. when using a GUI builder where it's a bit complicated to change the creation code for a button, or when you need to use already existing components.

Comment: But if we want to do this just to find what is the source of event, we can user setActionCommand() and getActionCommand().

Comment: To get the *source* of the event you have to use `getSource()`, **not** getActionCommand().

Comment: @VallabhPatade - I don't think there is a setter. There is only getter. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand%28%29

Comment: @davidblaine: you supply the action command in the constructor. If I recall correctly, when the button is creating the `ActionEvent` it will pass the action command from the `Action` associated with the `JButton`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - how do I do that ? Isn't the ActionEvent generated by the system ?

Comment: @davidblaine: the source that calls the `actionPerformed()` method will create the `ActionEvent` event, passing itself as the source. Why don't you just try it? Or read the JavaDocs, or check the source?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Please consider accepting my edits to your answer. I feel that it makes the code easier to understand quickly. There is no getSource(String ABC) method. I saw only getSource().

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to change the Action event.You can do this,

```
SuperJButton jButton = (SuperJButton) actionEvent.getSource();
jButton.getId() 
jButton.getNumber()
```

Answer (score 1):

From `MVC` point of view: `JButton` is a `view`, and `JButton` class is not better place to something like `id`. Much better place for an id is in your own `ButtonModel` implementation.

Comment: Nice idea, but it will also require to sub-class JButton, in order to ensure that the correct `ButtonModel` is used.

Comment: Agree with you, also my solution can be inappropriate if there is a plan to use a single model for multiple buttons

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - actually no extension needed, just configure the button with your custom model (a simple factory can do it ;-)

Comment: buttonModels are rarely shareable - except you want to let bhe buttons dance in sync :-)